# Powershell script for getting service account password

Tags: powershell

We have some old servers that have some service accounts for Services, but we don't know the passwords for the accounts.

It is not possible to reset the password because the same service account could be used somewhere else that we don't kno.

Is there any way to get the old password of this service accounts from `services.msc` ?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/01/22/password-for-a-service-account-in-powershell.aspx) will serve your purpose.

Comment: Are they local or domain accounts?

Comment: Your best bet is to start using a new account that isn't used somewhere else, of which you're free to control the password. Consider making this a virtual service account so you never need to manage the password again. It *is* possible to extract the stored password data of the SCM, at least in theory, but not in any supported way -- you're looking at things like LSASS hackery and Mimikatz. The cost of understanding these things likely outweighs fixing your setup.